# Capturing mouseMove event in ember.js

Tags: events, ember.js, capture, mousemove

I'm trying to implement a slider view in ember.js; for that I would need to capture the `mouseMove` event even if it leaves the view that first received it. In pure js I would do something like this:

```
element.addEventListener 'mousemove', ..., true   // true means 'capture event'
```

This also has the nice side effect of having the event being fired on the capturing element even if the mouse leaves the browser window, mimicking the way UI controls behave in native applications.

I don't seem to be able to find a way to do that in ember.js but I'm sure I'm overlooking something. If not, then what is the recommended way of doing something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `EventDispatcher`, which handles setting up the default event handlers on the root element (typically `body`), does not do anything to scope `mouseMove` to to a view other than that in which it is actually happening.

You can look into `onDrag`, `onDragStart`, and `onDragEnd` (`dragStart`, `drag`, `dragEnd` in ember parlance) events which per spec should be fired on the source element, and thus fire on your view regardless of where they happen.

You CAN manually assign handlers to `body` yourself. Add handlers for `mouseUp` and `mouseMove` in a `mouseLeave` handler, and remove them in your `mouseEnter` (to prevent duplication) and `mouseUp` handlers.

The simplest way to do this would be to use `on`:

```
$('body').on('mouseMove.custom', $.proxy(this.yourHandler, this));
```

and then to remove:

```
$('body').off('mouseMove.custom')
```

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the bone-headed scoping of the mouseMove event right back to your view. The listeners should just be on 'body' with no selector scoping.

Answer (score 3):

An update for people viewing an old question. Now components contain a `mouseMove` and other event handlers built in, as well as the ability ability to add custom ones.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/handling-events/

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    mouseMove() {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```